# ReflectionException; Class...\Foo\BarV1Interface does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1

When running the compile command `setup:di:compile` it leaves me with this error;

```
[ReflectionException]
Class \Magento\Framework\Module\Service\Magento\Framework\Module\Service\Foo\BarV1Interface does not exist
```

The full stack trace;

```
Exception trace:
() at ./setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:173
ReflectionClass->__construct() at ./setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:173
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->collectEntities() at ./setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php:77
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\ApplicationCodeGenerator->doOperation() at ./setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at ./setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:187
Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at ./vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at ./vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at ./vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at ./vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at ./vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at ./bin/magento:23
```

I've found this particular class in;

```
vendor/magento/module-webapi/Test/Unit/_files/test_interfaces.php
```

And the `module-webapi` is indeed included, so I wouldn't know why it isn't included

Running Magento `2.1.8` and php `7.0.22`.

I tried all kinds of things; emptying the `var/generation` directory, clearing the whole `var` directory, clearing only the cache, deleting the `vendor` dir and run a `composer update`, but nothing helped me out... I don't know where to start debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what caused this problem. Apparently magento doesn't like paths with either spaces or parentheses. I had both somewhere down the line... Changed the folder name and it was all fixed.